# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter - how to change database query after creation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

**Problem**

I have a list of items that are displayed in android through a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. I create this adapter with a database reference on all the list of items (let's say "posts"). The post displays also the category and if the user click on the category, I would like to update the list to display only items on that category.

**Solution I tried that doesn't work**
I put a click listener on the "category" textview and when the user click on it I tried to instantiate a new adapter with the new database query but it doesn't work.

Other ideas:
Do it outside the adpater:
create a new Intent to relaunch the fragment and create a new adapter with the new query

**Question**
Did someone deal with the same situation where on a user click you want to filter the original list of items retrieved by the adpater?
What is the best solution?

**Details**

```
protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post post, final int position) {


    /* Set the post text, author and category */
    viewHolder.postText.setText(post.getText());
    viewHolder.postAuthor.setText(post.getAuthor());
    viewHolder.postCategory.setText(post.getCategory());

    /* Set a listener on category so that 
      I refresh data with only that category */
    viewHolder.quoteCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        Post selectedPost = getItem(position);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String category = selectedPost.getCategory();

            // !!!! NOW I HAVE TO CHANGE DATA SET !!! ///
```

I think now I can create a new Fragment with a new adapter with correct Db reference... but is this the best way? 
Is there a way to use the same Adapater inside the populate view passing another query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use updateOptions(options) after building options with the new query.

`updateOptions(newOptions)`

A sample

```
fun changeQuery() {
        val newQuery = mBaseQuery
            .orderByChild("timestamp")
            .limitToLast(100)

        // Make new options
        val newOptions = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(newQuery, Post::class.java)
            .build()

        // Change options of adapter.
        mAdapter.updateOptions(newOptions)
    }
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/update-queries-without-changing-recyclerview-adapter-using-firebaseui-android-32098b3082b2)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `.notifyDatasetChanged()` on your adapter when the click occurs. After you have changed the dataset with the fresh firebase data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is not to notify a change in data set... the problem is how to change dataset once the adpater has already been created.

"after you have changed the dataset" ... how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You do not change the query, you create a new adapter and query, replace the adapter in the recycler view, and clean up the old one.

Here is an example, "changing the query" based on a selection in a spinner:

```
   locationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view,
         final int i, final long l) {
            if (locationSpinner.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                final Location location = locationSpinner.getSelectedItem();
                final String indexString = String.format("open/%s/", location.getId());
                final Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference("availabilities")
                        .orderByChild("statusLocationDateKey")
                        .startAt(indexString + "0") // simplified for example
                        .endAt(indexString + "9"); // simplified for example
                adapter = new ListingAdapter(query);
                final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter oldAdapter = 
                        (FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) listing.getAdapter();
                listing.setAdapter(adapter);
                if (oldAdapter != null) {
                    oldAdapter.cleanup();
                }
            }
        }
```

*Note: `ListingAdapter` is a subclass of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and `listing` is a `RecyclerView`.*

Also be sure to include a null check in the on destroy
for the activity or fragment, since with the code above, there is no guarantee that the adapter was ever initialized, for example:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.cleanup();
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change database query after creation you need to `stopListening` to the adapter and then create new adapter with new query and `startListening` to adapter

Sample Code is below

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter fireBaseAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);


locationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
Query query = databaseReference.child("yourChild").orderByChild("keyName");

    getDataFireBase(query);

    return view;
}

public void getDataFireBase(final Query query) {
    if (fireBaseAdapter!= null)
        fireBaseAdapter.stopListening();       


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<YourModelClass> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<YourModelClass>()
            .setQuery(query,YourModelClass.class)
            .build();

    fireBaseAdapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(fireBaseAdapter);
    fireBaseAdapter.startListening();
}



 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int i, final long l) {



Query query = databaseReference.child("yourChild").orderByChild("keyName"); // your new query

    getDataFireBase(query);




        }

 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fireBaseAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    fireBaseAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for update the firebase data. Here I update two parameters, that passed to function as title and body.

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {

        String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
        Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
        Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
        childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
        childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

        mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
    }
```

I think this will helps you.

Comment: thanks for the answer by I don't want to update/change data... I want to filter them differently in the UI.

The solution I've found it's to create a new fragment and call it with a new firebaseadapter where I put as argument another firebase query in the constructor